# React Hooks - Why is useEffect not being fired, when property changes

Tags: reactjs

I've got an issue with my Reactjs app. It's hard to explain the whole story, so I will try to concentrate me on the issue itself.

I have a component (`ProductSetup`), which shows different setups based on a given type. Therefore I created plain javascript classes (in this case `GoodsSetupWizard`), because I needed to be able to call different functions within this class. Also in this class there is a property `step`.
A class looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ProductName from '../components/productName.component';
import { updateProduct } from '../../../../../../factories/productSetup.factory';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from '../../../../../../utils/utils';

class GoodsSetupWizardController {
    constructor(props) {
        this.product = props.product;
        this._step = props.step;


        Object.defineProperty(this, 'step', {
            get() { return this._step; },
            set(newValue) { this._step = newValue; },
        });
    }

    getComponent(step) {
        ...
    }

    isNextButtonDisabled(step) {
        ...
    }

    needsNextStepToBeSkipped(direction) {
        ...
    }

    increaseDecreaseStep(direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case '+':
                this.step = this.step + 1;
                break;
            case '-':
                this.step = this._step - 1;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error();
        }
    }
}

export default GoodsSetupWizardController;
```

As I said, there is a property `step` in this class. At some point I increase the value within the class as you can see in the method `increaseDecreaseStep()`.

In my `ProductSetup` component, I'm using `useEffect` to watch this property.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ... //some code here
},[productSetupWizard?.step]);
```

But when I increase the value within the class, the `useEffect` will not recognize it. Why? Any solutions to this?

### Update

`productSetupWizard` is an instance of `GoodsSetupWizardController`

Comment: Class and useEffect ???? Paste your whole code to understand.

Comment: What is `productSetupWizard`? Do you set state to update it? A useEffect will only get run if the component rerenders, and it will only rerender if you set state somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear. Please see my updated question. `productSetupWizard` is an instance of `GoodsSetupWizardController`

Comment: React has no idea when you mutate the `productSetupWizard`. The only way in react to cause a rerender is to set state. The new state must be a new, immutable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` just update with stateful dependencies, As I understood, the `productSetupWizard` is an instance of `GoodsSetupWizardController` class, but it is not stateful.

What I mean by stateful, is the value generated by reacting hooks, like `useState` and `useMemo`

Answer (score 1):

Let's think for a moment about the purpose of the `useEffect` hook. It allows you to describe an effect that you want occur as a result of changing state. "What is considered state?", you kindly ask. Props and hook state (`useState`, `useMemo`, etc.) of course! In this example, the `useEffect` callback will never get called since the fields of `productSetupWizard` are not stateful and do trigger re-render.

tldr; If it won't trigger a re-render then it won't trigger the `useEffect` either.